# Can Jena RdfDataMgr write turtle with typed literals

Tags: rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

Is there a way to get Jena's RdfDataMgr write() to maintain types of literals.

Here's my code which inserts a triple with a typed literal, and them dumps the TURTLE:

```
String insertQuery = "prefix XMLSchema:<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
            "INSERT DATA " + 
            "  { GRAPH <http://name>   { " + 
            "        <#book1> <#name> \"Name\"^^XMLSchema:string  " + 
            "      }  } ";


    org.apache.jena.query.Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.createTxnMem();
    ds.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    try {
        UpdateAction.parseExecute(insertQuery, ds);
    } finally { ds.commit(); ds.end() ; }

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    RDFDataMgr.write(stream, ds.getNamedModel("http://name"), RDFFormat.TURTLE_PRETTY);
    String str = stream.toString();
    System.out.println(str);
```

This prints:

```
 <file:///C:/Users/200001934/workspace-current/sparqlgraph/semTK/sparqlGraphLibrary/#book1>
    <file:///C:/Users/200001934/workspace-current/sparqlgraph/semTK/sparqlGraphLibrary/#name>
            "Name" .
```

But I'm looking for Turtle with the type of **"Name"** preserved.   Something like:

```
<file:///C:/Users/200001934/workspace-current/sparqlgraph/semTK/sparqlGraphLibrary/#book1>
    <file:///C:/Users/200001934/workspace-current/sparqlgraph/semTK/sparqlGraphLibrary/#name>
            "Name"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
```

Is there a different RDFFormat, or a setting in RDFDataMgr, or am I missing a more fundamental concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RDF 1.1 `"abc"` is exactly the same RDF literal as `"abc"^^xsd:string`. They are two ways of writing the same RDFTerm. The without-^^ form is preferred, as mentioned in the RDF 1.1 spec. This is true in SPARQL as well - the `^^XMLSchema:string` is unnecessary.

Comment: This is helpful knowledge.  However, when I import this turtle into Virtuoso and run SPARQL with a values clause like
` "VALUES ?x {"Name"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> } ` it doesn't match.  Perhaps I shouldn't use this kind of values clause.

Comment: Virtuoso does not support RDF 1.1, only RDF 1.0. See github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/… Ideally, be consistent and use the plain form everywhere. Otherwise, use FILTER equality ("abc" is equals to "abc"^^xsd:string in SPARQL) or use STRDT to convert in the query to ^^xsd:string form, or cast with `xsd:string("simple term")`.